# navigation error- syntaxerror: Unexpected character after line continuation character

Tags: python, syntax

[screenshot of code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3MFJ.png)

I'm new to python and programming. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Can someone tell me what's wrong with the code?

Comment: Please copy and paste both your code and error message. Don't use screenshots. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It looks that in your .py file is a line that contains `e:\"> cd ...". That's an erratic python code. And `\` character is treated as line continuation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.